# SAML VerificationException in WAS7 in java

Tags: java, saml

Could you please help us for the SAML Verification issue.

We have the application for SAML Single Sing on, it is working for all the environments,Now we are moving to **WAS7**, when we install the same application we are getting the **VerificationException** while verifying the SamlResponse with publickey.

*samlResponse.verify(idpPublicKey);*

while executing above statement, we are getting the following exception.

**org.eclipse.higgins.saml2idp.saml2.XMLElement$VerificationException: Invalid signature value.
    at org.eclipse.higgins.saml2idp.saml2.XMLElement.verify(XMLElement.java:283)**

We used the higgings jar file for SAML Validation.

Please kindly provide the reason/solution.

Comment: Where are you getting the idpPublicKey from? could it be that the webserver provided this and the new one has not been configures to do so?

Comment: Is there any nested cause for the exception?

Comment: Hi Stefan,Thanks for Reply. we are getting the idpPublickey from the client certificate , which is shared by client either in .pem file or .cer file

Comment: Is there any nested cause for the exception?

Comment: We got only the exception is org.eclipse.higgins.saml2idp.saml2.XMLElement$VerificationException: Invalid signature value. at org.eclipse.higgins.saml2idp.saml2.XMLElement.verify(XMLElement.java:283)

Comment: Ok, no idea, my best guess are that you are reading the wrong certificte for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a problem with references - the XML signature validation uses reference to the signed data inside XML document. In JDK 1.6.21+ the reference checking is much stricter than before, which often results in errors. Full discussion here:

http://ipsec.pl/node/1119